# React/Redux - Component not updating despite Redux state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update a map component in my app. I receive the location details from redux and I can see the state change in the Redux Dev Tools or even on my browser console but the map component does not seem to update unless I go to another route then return to the route containing the component.

I have read about Redux needing state to be immutable and I have tried all the suggested options to try to keep my state immutable but I still have not been successful.

#### Location Reducer

```js
const initialState = {
  gps: [],
};

export default function locationsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    
    case FETCH_LOCATIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        gps: action.locations,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### MapResults Component

```js
class MapResults extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 0.0236,
      lng: 37.9062
    },
    zoom: 6.5
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '70vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={ key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
        {this.props.coordinates.gps.map((location, index) => {
          return(
            <Tooltip 
              lat={location.latitude}
              lng={location.longitude}
              title={location.address_name}
              key={index}>
              <Avatar src="/images/gps.svg" />
            </Tooltip>
          )
        })}
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { coordinates: state.locations };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MapResults);
```

The fetchLocation method is being triggered correctly and coordinates being fetched and can be viewed in the dev tools. I just have to navigate to a different route then come back to the map route for the markers to be updated on the map.

I expect the map component to update immediately the redux state changes  when the location state has been updated.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

### EDIT

My index reducer where I am combining my reducers

#### Root Reducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import individual from "./individualReducer";
import locations from "./locationsReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  individual,
  locations
});
```

**Redux Dev Tools clearly shows state is updated as you can see in image**
[image: reduxdevtools screenshot]
**Map after redux state is updated**

You can see no markers
[image: map immediately redux state is updated]
**Map after I navigate to another route and back to map route**

You can see markers are updated
[image: Map after I navigate to a different route and back to the map route]

Comment: I am sorry but your google map api key is exposed. Be careful with your api key, please use env variable.

Comment: Hello @reizkian, thank you so much for letting me know, I guess I was pretty careless 2 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Location reducer, the state name is `gps`, so the state name should be mapped in the component. Because the state `gps` is updated. Please change the state name as to below

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { coordinates: state.gps };
};
```

Comment: Hello Nagesh, thank you for this. I have updated the question to include my root reducer where the status of the locationReducer is named as **locations** that is why I mapped my coordinates to state.locations.

Comment: @Kimkykie If the state is changing then you need to assign the state name, you can change the assignment like state.locations.gps. And in your map(), you can just loop through this.props.coordinates.

Comment: I have tried that too and I am facing the same issue. My other reducer is updating redux state and updating components perfectly but this location one only updates state once I leave the route and navigate back to it again. You can check my screenshots. Thank you

Comment: @Kimkykie Can you add code for componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate().  Please log the location in componentDidUpdate() as well and please add the output of componentDidUpdate() after the state update.